# Is using dollar quoting $$ and removing $ from input enough to avoid SQL injection in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

I'm coding some logic in embeded Freeswitch LUA and built in database handling 
does not allow parametric input for SQL, so I need to escape the input.
I'm sure my `username` should not have `$` symbols in, is it safe to escape
all `$` symbols from input and use dollar quoting or there are some 
workaround to hack and insert injection here?

```
username = string.gsub(username,'[$]','')
string.format([[SELECT id FROM users WHERE username =  $$%s$$]], username)
```

Comment: Not safe, better not use this product between the web and a DB.

Comment: looks like it'd work (I don't recognise the source language there could be other problems), but why not use the more common methods of string quoting? I mean how is that easier than just doubling all the apostrophes?

Comment: if you want to make code review's head explode put a GUID between the $$ at each end :)

Comment: @Jasen indeed using dynamic random string when generating query like $RANDOM$completely anything here""''"'""""'''"$RANDOM$ can add some kind of security ever if not escaping input at all